# Ten votes to delete a question is not working retroactively?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

The recently introduced rule that 10 delete votes is enough even for old highly upvoted questions seems not to work for questions that already have more than 10 votes.

For example, this question has 11 delete votes without being deleted

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469696/what-is-your-most-useful-c-c-utility

As my vote seems to be one of those 11, I cannot test if yet another vote will trigger a delete.

Comment: Any now it only needs **8 (eight)** votes to undelete

Comment: Right. :-) Also seems like the `next vote >= 10` triggered a delete.

Comment: Which was me...

Comment: And after it has been deleted for half an hour, it already has three undelete votes.

Comment: Despite being one of the people who voted to delete, I changed my mind and cast an "undelete" vote. I think this should be one of the "historical interest" questions—available, but protected. Did we ever figure out how to nominate questions for that status?

Comment: And I don't agree with Cody, obviously. This is the kind of off-topic/non-constructive questions we quickly close nowadays. If we believe that they collect valuable info over time, why don't we want *more* of these to stay open and collect even more info?